# strspn Strange behavior under c++, why?

Tags: c++, pointers, strlen

Here is a program I made:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    char frase1 [100];
    char frase2 [100];

    cin >> frase1;
    cin >> frase2;

    char * parola1 = strtok (frase1, " .");
    char * parola2 = strtok (frase2, " .");

    int i;

    i = strspn (parola1, parola2);

    int j;

    j = strspn (parola2, parola1);

    cout << i << " " << j;

    return 0;
}
```

It should ask for 2 sentences that will be stored into `frase1` and `frase2`, then two tokenizers set two pointers to the first word of their respective array, then I should get back the values `i` and `j`, wich are ints given by the `strspn` function.

So when the terminal shows up should be able to put, for example, `"veritas omnia vincit"` and `"vetirsa omnia vincit"` and then get `7 7` as output.

Instead, I insert the first sentence and it returns the values of the strspn between the first and the second word of the first sentence (veritas, omnia).

This is an attempt at isolating a problem showing up in a bigger program wich I'll show you right away:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
void eliminaVocali (char [], char []);
int controlloAnagramma (char*, char []);
bool controlloParola (char[]);



int main() {

    char frase [10];

    cin >> frase;

    cout << "yolo1";

    char fraseCorretta [100];

    cout << "yolo";

    eliminaVocali(frase, fraseCorretta);

    if (controlloParola(fraseCorretta)) cout << "TRUE!!";
    else cout << "FALSE :(";

}

void eliminaVocali (char frase [], char fraseCorretta []){

    int counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){

        if (frase[i] != 'a' && frase[i] != 'e' && frase[i] != 'i' && frase[i] != 'o' && frase[i] != 'u'){

            fraseCorretta[counter] = frase[i];
            counter++;

        }

    }

}

bool controlloParola (char frase []){

    char * parola = strtok (frase, " .");

    if (controlloAnagramma (parola, frase) > 2) return true;

    while (parola != NULL){

        parola = strtok(NULL, " .");
        if (controlloAnagramma (parola, frase) > 2) return true;

    }

    return false;

}

int controlloAnagramma (char * parola, char frase []){

    int counter = 0;

    char * check = new char [100];

    check = frase;

    char * parola2 = strtok (check, " .");

    if (strlen(parola) == strlen(parola2) && strlen(parola) == strspn(parola, parola2) && strlen(parola) == strspn(parola2, parola)) counter++;

    while (parola2 != NULL){

        parola2 = strtok (NULL, " .");

        if (strlen(parola) == strlen(parola2) && strlen(parola) == strspn(parola, parola2) && strlen(parola) == strspn(parola2, parola)) counter++;}

    delete[] check;
    return counter;

    }
```

This program receive a sentence, delete all the vowels from it and then check if among the words newly formed there are 2 wich one is anagram of another.

eliminaVocali delete the vowels
controlloParola takes one word of the sentence at a given time and send it to controlloAnagramma
controlloAnagramma take the word and search into the whole sentence for an anagram

This program gives

> 1 [main] testingstuff 93304 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile:
>   Dumping stack trace to testingstuff.exe.stackdump

Where testingstuff is the program name.

The problem should be into controlloAnagramma, where I use `strlen` and `strspn`.

Know fact that can be useful: Neither of the 2 yolo `cout` into the main is ever printed.

Please note this is a didactic program, I can only use c++ with `<cstring>`.

The question is, why does the `strspn` command behave this way? It should solve the big program. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

```
cin >> frase1;
cin >> frase2;
```

Shoud be:

```
cin.getline(frase1, 100);
cin.getline(frase2, 100);
```

As @anton-savin pointed out.

Also

```
check = frase;
```

Should be

```
strcpy (check, frase);
```

Error persist anyway.

Comment: TLDR; Debuggers are your friend.

Comment: I know its TL but rules say to be exaustive, maybe too much?

Answer (score 2):

```
cin >> frase1;
cin >> frase2;
```

`operator>>` reads strings word by word, so `frase1` becomes `"veritas"` and `frase2` becomes `"omnia"`. To read the input line by line use [`getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline):

```
cin.getline(frase1, 100);
cin.getline(frase2, 100);
```

Comment: You are right, I've just tried out your snippet on my first program and it works heavenly, still, if used into my second program (the big one) it gives the same error. Thanks anyway this was a huge improvement for me, I upvoted, will show my vote at 15 reputation, pretty new here.